# Returning file or directory not found, but no file or directory mentioned in bash command?

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess, paramiko

I am trying to dump info from a database with a specific command I was given.

```
 db_dump = open('{}/dbdump.txt'.format(directory_name), 'w+')
    foo = subprocess.call('PGPASSWORD="-------" pg_dump -h vm-postgres -d "qa-test{}db" -U "qatest" -a -x'.format(str(driverlabelnum)), shell=True)
    print str(foo)
    db_dump.write(foo)
    db_dump.close()
    print "Done dumping"
```

It works just fine when I copy paste it to the command line, but bugs out when I try to automate it through subprocess.call().

I tried to do this a couple of different ways, but I keep running into this error...

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/csd-user/test/libs/utils/butler.py", line 427, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/csd-user/test/libs/utils/butler.py", line 424, in main
    b.log_bug_exec(url)
  File "/home/csd-user/test/libs/utils/butler.py", line 52, in log_bug_exec
    cls.process_file(stdout)
  File "/home/csd-user/test/libs/utils/butler.py", line 109, in process_file
    cls.create_artifacts(nums[0], nums[1])
  File "/home/csd-user/test/libs/utils/butler.py", line 269, in create_artifacts
    foo = csd_shell_lib.check_output('PGPASSWORD="-------" pg_dump -h vm-postgres -d "qa-test{}db" -U "qatest" -a -x'.format(str(driverlabelnum)))
  File "/home/csd-user/test/libs/jupiter/csd_shell_lib.py", line 70, in check_output
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd.split(), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/opt/cs/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/cs/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/opt/cs/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I know that the subprocess.call command splits the command into an array/list of `substrings(.split(' '))`, and that it is calling PGPASSWORD="" by itself. However, I have no idea how to avoid that happening and could not find it online.

P.S. The other problem I'm having is a Errno 13 permission denied with Paramiko trying to .get a file. I don't know/understand how to log in as `su` or `sudo` without the program prompting me for a password (with just the singular paramiko command) (I could do it with ssh, but I'd rather not).

Comment: what is the full traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PGPASSWORD` is an environment variable. You can't use subprocess.call when you have to give a specific environment variable. You can use subprocess.Popen instead and pass environment variables [as a dedicated parameter](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

```python
import os, subprocess
env = os.environ.copy()
env['PGPASSWORD'] = '------'
subprocess.Popen('pg_dump -h vm-postgres -d "qa-test{}db" -U "qatest" -a -x'.format(str(driverlabelnum)), env=env, shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks man, that works beautifully. Could I pass multiple env variables to the Popen command? Thanks! @devunt

Comment: @Ian Yes. Just add more items to `env` dictionary like `env['ANOTHER'] = 'VALUE'` before call Popen()

Answer (score 0):

The traceback says that your particular error is due to `cmd.split()` in `csd_shell_lib.check_output()`: you shouldn't split on whitespace an arbitrary shell command. Though even `shlex.split()` won't work in this case because the first item sets an envvar.

Either use `subprocess` module directly with the shell command passed as a string:

```
cmd = 'PGPASSWORD="-------" pg_dump -h vm-postgres -d "qa-test{}db" -U qatest -a -x'.format(driverlabelnum)
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```

Or (better) split the command manually and remove `shell=True`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import subprocess

with open(os.path.join(directory_name, 'dbdump.txt'), 'wb', 0) as db_dump:
    subprocess.check_call(['pg_dump', '-h', 'vm-postgres',
                           '-d', 'qa-test{}db'.format(driverlabelnum),
                           '-U', 'qatest', '-a', '-x'],
                           env=dict(os.environ, PGPASSWORD="-------"),
                           stdout=db_dump)
print("Done dumping")
```

Note:

- `check_call()` is used to raise an exception if `pg_dump` fails
- `stdout=db_dump` is used to redirect the output of `pg_dump` to the file directly without loading it into memory
- there is no `shell=True`
- no quotes around `-d`, `-U` values
- no unnecessary `str()` call
- `dict(os.environ, PGPASSWORD="-------")` is used to create the environment `dict` for the child process

Add `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to redirect stderr to stdout (and therefore dump it with the rest of the data into the file) if you need it.